# Предварительный просмотр контрола

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы можно было отобразить в canvas любой один контрол из списка доступных при условии что его размеры будут подогнаны под размеры canvas и он будет расположен строго по центру с небольшим отступом от границ canvas. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, любой из доступных в WPF контролов? Их очень много, это раз. А затем, вам придётся для каждого контрола каким-то образом скормить ему подходящие параметры. Потому что без параметров, например, `TextBlock` выглядит никак. И `Grid`. И ListBox без наполнения. И `Border` без `BorderThickness`.

Comment: @VladD Ну ни всё, пусть 4 wpf контрола но показываются без проблем

Comment: А наличие именно canvas принципиально? Если заменить Canvas на Border, получается просто: `<Border Padding="30"><Button>I'm a Button</Button></Border>`.